# Is it possible to offer two separate bounties for the same question by the same user simultaneously?

Tags: support, bounties

Assume that someone has asked a question and some good answers have been posted. He wants to start a bounty and his reason is **"One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty"**

Can he offer two separate bounties at the same time? Or he should offer the second bounty 24 hours after awarding the first one?

Can he offer a bounty and then award it for two answers? I mean can he break the bounty in two parts when he wants to award it?

Comment: One thing to correct that isn't mentioned in the answer: after awarding the first bounty, you can immediately start the second bounty, you need to wait 24 hours just to award it, not start it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks a lot! What a bout acceptance an answer? If I start a bounty and accept an answer during the 7 days and award the bounty to that accepted answer, can I start another bounty and award it to **another answer**?

Comment: Yes of course, when the bounty is active, you'll see "+50" (or +100 etc) next to each answer. You can choose any answer you like, no matter if accepted, old, new, or even got a bounty in the past. (Only exception being deleted, locked, or your own answers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A question can only have one bounty at a time. Note that a second bounty will need to be twice the size of the first one till you get to the upper limit for bounty size.

The above and more is covered in the [help centre article on bounties.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

You can't break a single bounty in two either.